# Помогите с Visual Studio Code, как сделать терминал на git bash

Tags: visual-studio-code

Проблема заключается в том что вчера все работало нормально, когда на папке нажимал Open in Integrated terminal оно открывало в терминале с git bash, сегодня уже когда делаю такую же операцию оно открывает в PowerShell, хотя я делал что git bash стоил по дефолту главным, помогите исправить пожалуйста

Comment: Поставьте cmd по дефолту.

Comment: Где и как я должен сделать

Comment: Так и напиши в гугл.

Answer (score 0):

Окей, насколько я понял проблему, то решается так.

**1**. Открываем терминал: **Ctrl + `**.

**2**. Выбираем **Настройка параметров терминала**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3**. В открывшемся окне укажем путь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Открыть VSCode.
2. Открыть терминал "Ctrl + `".
3. В открывшемся терминале нажать на стрелочку вниз рядом с плюсиком [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Затем выбрать пункт "Select Default Profile"
5. В открывшемся сверху окошке выбираем желаемый терминал[image: введите сюда описание изображения]